# The <option> disabled attribute is not supported in IE, prior version 8. Any workaround?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

The disabled attribute is not supported in IE, prior version 8 for HTML `<option>` disabled Attribute. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp

What options do we have to customize the look and make the field read only?

**Warning!**
Read the question twice, as we don't ask about `<input disabled>` we ask about `<option disabled>`

Comment: "The disabled attribute is not supported in IE, prior version 8." I don't believe that.

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/disabled looks like its supported since 5.5 ;)

Comment: @BoltClock I updated the question, it's about the `<option>` tag.

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve by making an option disabled? An entirely different approach might be needed. To begin with, why have the option in a menu if the user is not supposed to be able to select it? So it would seem to be natural to create the select menu without the options that you now have as disabled, and add them into the select element in a situation where you now turn a disabled option to enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"The disabled attribute is not supported in IE, prior version 8 for HTML  disabled Attribute."*

This is entirely untrue.

Even IE7 dims an `<option disabled>` element and prevents selecting it (IE6 however doesn't).

Comment: Guess you can't trust w3schools huh =/

Comment: @Jack No, you can't. I've removed them from my Google search results via personal block list. They're more into SEO than into being helpful.

Comment: Using 'disabled' for option in a select box (in IE7) I could both see the option as well as select it (contrary to what Tomalak says). Should be easy enough to test. Maybe Tomalak can explain why this happens? Use IE7.0.5730

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion (and this is not tested at all) would be to add an event handler on the `<option>` tag and have it `return false;` to prevent it from being selected.

Alternatively, you could hook onto the `select onchange` handler and revert to the old value when the selected value is not supposed to be clicked. Browsers that do support `disabled`  will not be affected, so that might work for you.